# Не запускается бот Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

вначале были ошибки связанные с пятой и шестой строкой,затем все проблемы пропали и получилось это(ботт должен отвечать тоже что и пишут)
https://prnt.sc/YY1kU0PnyN5Z
как исправить это,ботт не отвечает:https://prnt.sc/94Zjif9kI17n

Comment: 1. Выложите весь свой код в виде текста, а не скриншотами (тем более со сторонних сайтов); 2. Нежелательно публиковать номер токена и прочую конфиденциальную информацию в вопросе, иначе Вашего бота запросто смогут угнать или что-то вроде этого

Comment: У меня не открываются ваши ссылки

Comment: @4500zenja, не стоит запрашивать «весь код». стоит запрашивать [mcve].

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, Вы правы, я имел в виду весь код, выложенный в скриншотах

Comment: по скрину сразу видно проблемы с отступами `if __name__=="__main__"`  не должно быть внутри функции

Answer (score -1):

Бот просто не запущен

Не забудьте использовать команду `asyncio.run(функция())`

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot

BOT_TOKEN = ""

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
    ...

asyncio.run(main())
```

Базовые примеры: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram